# How to save an image using es file explorer

Tags: android

I can currently save an image in my app using the Es File explorer to a shared windows folder.

But what I want to know is, how can I eliminate the process of selecting the folder and specify it in code?

```
public void SaveToNetwork() {
   Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);

   shareIntent.SetType("*/*");
   shareIntent.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(App._dir, App._file.Name)));

   shareIntent.SetPackage("com.estrongs.android.pop");

   StartActivity(shareIntent);
}
```

I don't want to use the file explorer. I just want to directly save it to the folder, or at least change the default selected folder to the correct one.

Comment: android provides File class and outpustream class for this purpose http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

android provides [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) class and [outpustream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html) class for this purpose following is a sample code which recives the bitmap and save it to specified folder and then add you image to gallery content provider

```
 private String savePic(Bitmap bitmapImage) {
            try {

                //bitmapImage=drawView.getmCanvasBitmap();

                File dir = new File(
                        Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                        "youfoldername");

                dir.mkdir();
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                    String path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/youfilename"
                            + c.getTimeInMillis() + ".Jpg";
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                    // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image
                    // to
                    // the OutputStream

                    bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    fos.close();


                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path);
                    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("image/Jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            Uri.parse("file://" + path));
                    startActivity(intent);

                    return path;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I want to save to a Shared Windows Folder on the network